# Populate the Year&month correspondng cell value based on text match using Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am working on the below sheet. How I can run a formula to loop into the column D rows(D9 to D20) and find the exact match in the column A rows(A4 and A5) and then populate values to **"Table1"** from the **Range 'B4:G5'** based on matching year,month &Team

Output values to be like in Column "Value":
[image]

I tried by using "VLOOKUP formula" and in one more sheet(References) I have given the months with values, but not getting the required result.

[image]

Formula I used :

```
=VLOOKUP([@Team],A:A,(([@Year]-2019)*12+VLOOKUP([@Month],References!R:S,2,0)+1),0)
```

Comment: Get rid of the merged cells and it will be a matter of a simple SUMIFS().

Comment: But if I do not merge the year value to be repeated to all cells?

Comment: Yes repeat the values across the cells, with merged cells the value is only in the upper left cell of the merged area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the Post #.01 Table layout

"Source table" housed in `A2:G5`

In output value "Table 1" `D10`, formula copied down :

```
=VLOOKUP(A10,$A$4:$G$5,MATCH(C10,$B$3:$C$3,0)+MATCH(B10,$B$2:$G$2,0),0)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is exactly i am looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

Unmerge years and do array formula can work.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the formula,it is working perfect but i want to merge cells.